# Принять файл через Post запрос gin golang

Tags: golang, post, golang-gin

сервер:

```go
func main() {
    currentFileId = UNIQUE_FILE_ID_START
    log.Println("started ...")
    start()

    server := gin.Default()

    server.POST("/upload_file", uploadFile)
}

func uploadFile(c *gin.Context) {
    log.Println("inUploadFile")
    log.Println(c.PostFormArray("file")) // пробовал ещё методы, почему-то пустота везде, логи ниже

    //получить файл,записать файл логов ,проверить на 1 гиг, сохранить и отдать страницу
    c.File("./templates/index2.html")

}
// пробовал ещё такие методы
log.Println(c.PostForm("file"))
    log.Println(c.PostFormMap("file"))
    log.Println(c.GetPostForm("file"))
    log.Println(c.GetPostFormArray("file"))
    log.Println(c.PostFormArray("file"))
```

клиент:

```html
<html lang = "ru">
    <head>
       <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/staticCSS"> -->
   </head>
   <body>
        <div class = "main_block">
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/upload_file">
                <p>Загрузите ваш файл.</p>
                <p><input type="file" name="file">
                <input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

логи:

```
2023/08/24 16:26:24 inUploadFile
2023/08/24 16:26:24 [] ПОЧЕМУ ПУСТО???
[GIN] 2023/08/24 - 16:26:24 | 200 |   91.721559ms |  127.0.0.1 | POST    "/upload_file"
```

Почему в логах пусто? Как принять и сохранить файл из тела пост запроса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PostForm` и `PostFormArray` обрабатывают поля в формах, которые передаются как `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Так как файлы передаются в запросах как `multipart/form-data`, эти функции возвращают пустые строки.

Для работы с файлами в `gin` есть два пути. Первый: работать непосредственно с multipart. Второй: использовать специализированные методы `FormFile` и `SaveUploadedFile`

Вот пример

```go
func uploadFile(c *gin.Context) {
    log.Println("inUploadFile")
    log.Println("Content-Type:", c.Request.Header["Content-Type"])
    if body, err := io.ReadAll(c.Request.Body); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        log.Println("Body:", string(body))
        // Нужно заново прикрепить тело к запросу, так как после `ReadAll` тело пустое.
        c.Request.Body = io.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(body))
    }
    // Для проверки распечатка полей формы как application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    log.Println("PostFormArray", c.PostFormArray("file"))
    log.Println("PostForm", c.PostForm("file"))

    // Извлечение файлов из Multi-part
    form, _ := c.MultipartForm()
    log.Println("Form", form)
    for i, fh := range form.File["file"] {
        log.Println("File #", i)
        log.Println("  file name", fh.Filename)
        log.Println("  file size", fh.Size)
        // Чтение содержимого файла
        fileReader, _ := fh.Open()
        contents, _ := io.ReadAll(fileReader)
        log.Println("  file contents: ", string(contents))
        fileReader.Close()
    }

    // Использование специализированных методов
    file, err := c.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, "No file in the request")
        return
    }
    log.Println("File name:", file.Filename)

    //получить файл,записать файл логов ,проверить на 1 гиг, сохранить и отдать страницу
    c.SaveUploadedFile(file, "uploaded.bin")
    c.String(http.StatusOK, fmt.Sprintf("'%s' uploaded!", file.Filename))
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, всю ветку go на ruSO тянете на себе:)